# Problems with -て 来る

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form, subsidiary-verbs

> A: あの番組を見ましたか。
>   B: いいえ。見ようとしたら、息子が友達を連れて帰って**来たんです**。

I only know of ～て来る as an indicator that someone goes to do something and then returns, for example:

> ちょっとたばこを買って来ます。

But recently my textbook has used this construction in several sentences where this semantics doesn't seem to fit perfectly. 
I don't know, what would you make out of this sentence above? It doesn't seem to make sense to me to say that someone "returns and then returns".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

来たんです

=> They came here.

帰ったんです

=> They returned to somewhere

帰って来たんです（「帰って」「来たんです」)

=> They returned to somewhere and the place is here.

Answer (score 0):

- 帰ってくる = come back
- 買いに行く = go and get/buy